# Problem installing latest version of Python3

Tags: python, python3

Please when I want to install python3, I have the following error.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4+git20200505-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E:

Kindly assist me with the possible solutions. Thank you

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  You do realize that if you change the default version of python3, many Ubuntu tools will no longer work (as they were built for the python3 version your *unknown* release came with).

Comment: I am having Python 2.7.18. The OS i had this as i check: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal.

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` you have also a problem with your packagemangment. this`3.28.4+git20200505-0ubuntu18.04.2` points to a bionic package. and I agree with @user535733 do not mess up with default python versions.  `python3 --version` is the right command for python3 to check version.

Comment: I checked and I see I have: Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux

Comment: @nobody thanks. I ran grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ on the terminal and i had a long list showing many lines starting with grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. the deb is in red. But no further instructions. Please i want to confirm what I am suppose to see or do further, so i dont make more mistakes. Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and post the output from my command please.

Comment: Thank you all. problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the already-installed version of Python3. Doing so will break your system quite horribly.

- Use a Python Virtual Environment (venv) to run a different release of Python3. [Stackexchange thead explaining the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210)
- Alternately, use a Container or VM to run a different release of Ubuntu that has the version of Python3 that you want to use.

Comment: I am having Python 2.7.18. The OS i had this as i check: No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focal

Comment: Thank you very much. Please how do I Delete the wrong version repo from my sources.